# Can Model Observe View?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, oop

I am developing an application in Java, in my GUI I have several `JPanels` with a lot of settings on them, this would be the **View**. There is only one **Model** in the background of these several `JPanels`. Normally, I would *Observe* the **Model** from the `JPanels`.

I was just wondering, is it good practice to Observe **View** from the **Model**? Because, the user changes the **View**, and this change must effect my **Model**. Or am I missing some important principle here? Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its great you are questioning this.

What part you are missing that could help is a Controller.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller for an example.

Basically a controller is the mediator between a model and a view. It "Controls" the application. The only thing that your view should know about is the data that is being passed to it and how to display it. The only thing your Model should know about is data. The Controller ties these two together and contains the business logic that acts on the data and prepares it to pass to the view.

What you get from using this design is a loosley coupled and easy to test application. It really is elegant IMHO.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: My favorite MVC diagram: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/images/mvc-structure-generic.gif

Answer (score 2):

That would create unnecessary binding between the model and the view. But also think about an infinite cycle that you could get into.

What if the model was also updated by something other than a view, perhaps a web service? Then a change in the model through the web service will result a change in the view as the view would be observing the model. And also a change in the view will trigger a change in the model as the model is observing the view too. See the recursion here? It's not too difficult to bypass it, but will result in a really bad and unmaintainable design.

Comment: Yes, it was that infinite cycle made me ask this question. Things are getting clearer now, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

To tie your model and view together, one solution as has already been proposed is to add a Controller so that you have the full set of Model-View-Controller components implemented.  This introduces a very tight coupling between all three components, which from a unit-test perspective is not really desirable.

An alternative would be to consider the [Model-View-Presenter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter).  The Presenter would be the intermediary between the Model and the View, and would update the Model based on any input from the View, and would also be responsible for updating the view based on any changes in the Model. For your unit-tests, you would then be able to substitute a mock-View to test the Model, or a mock-Model to test the view (or mock both to test only the Presenter).

Comment: I agree, MVP is so much cleaner and there's only one interpretation.